# OpenGL Shader Compiles on Desktop, But Not Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, shader

I recently started learning opengl and still don't know very much about it. I was following a tutorial and wrote these two shaders:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400

in vec4 s_vPosition;
in vec4 s_vColor;
out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = s_vColor;
    gl_Position = s_vPosition;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400

in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main() {
    fColor = color;
}
```

They compile and work just fine on the desktop with OpenGL 3, but don't compile with OpenGL ES 2 on Android. I tried checking the shader output log, but it returned a blank string. Again, I am very new to this and my mistake is probably very simple, but any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nope, those shaders won't work fine with GL 3. If they do, that is so by a genorous implementation. Those shaders require GL 4.0 (although, for no particular reason, they could work with 3.x if a more reasonable version was selected). However, those shaders are not valid for ES2 in any case, which uses a different syntax (compatible to GLSL 1.20), so changing the version there won't help.

Comment: So what can I do to make it work?

Comment: Never mind, samgak's answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenGLES2 you don't use the `in` and `out` variable prefixes like in 3.0. Instead you use the following keywords:

- **attribute** Values that are passed in to the vertex shader per vertex
- **varying** Values that are passed from the vertex shader to the fragment shader
- **uniform** Global variables that you can set on a shader for all vertices and fragments (includes things like textures, but can also be scalar or vector types).

An `attribute` corresponds to an `in` in a vertex shader.
A `varying` corresponds to an `out` in a vertex shader and an `in` in a fragment shader. So, change your vertex shader to this:

```
attribute vec4 s_vPosition;
attribute vec4 s_vColor;
varying vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = s_vColor;
    gl_Position = s_vPosition;
}
```

and your fragment shader to this:

```
varying vec4 color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

`gl_FragColor` is a specially defined variable like `gl_Position` used for outputting the color from a fragment shader.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! My gratitude cannot be expressed in words. Now I am able to move on and continue learning openGL.